# RHELP on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Tags: linux

Is it possible to install Red Hat Enterprise Linux on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B? The model B's OS is on an SD Card. Can I just take this out and install the RHEL on a new SD card? Has anyone done this? Any issues? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Closest I know of is a Centos port that's a bit of AltArch amongst other bits :-) It's not clean or RedHat and I have not seen any move to port to the Pi 4

Have a look at the SIG at [centos.org](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/AltArch/armhfp) if you have a 3B+ handy.